# Postback Issue with Javascript Popup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this one, but I don't see anything quite the same. I have an ASPX page and using javascript to show a confirmation popup. When clicking on a button, the value I click isn't used but instead the previous value is. So if I click OK the first time it cancels. If I click OK a second time then it goes to OK, if I click cancel then it still goes to OK, I click cancel once again and it goes to cancel. I'm sure this is an issue with Postback, but I don't know how to resolve it since I'm not calling the javascript on a button click, but later on. I use my code behind to determine if a record is a duplicate and if so I show the popup letting the user know, and giving them the option to accept or cancel. If there is no duplicate then the script for the popup doesn't get called. So how do I resolve this issue?

Javascript in my ASPX

```
function Confirm() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm("Duplicate Record. Do you want to save?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

This is the code from my CS, called from a method after testing conditions.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, base.GetType(), "confirmation", "Confirm();", true);
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
if (confirmValue == "Yes")
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
}
else
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
}
```

NOTE: I am using AutoPostBack for several fields on the same page as its a data entry form and depending on what is selected for one field depends on how another field will be populated.

Comment: RegisterStartupScript used for add a js code to html from server side. it will not execute immediately. only after render html in browser. so you can't get confirm_value at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

In the markup, you can add a hidden field to monitor if duplicate data must be overwritten. In the example below, `btnSaveData` is the button that may already be present in your form.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenOverwriteData" runat="server" Value="false" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveData" runat="server" Text="Save data" OnClick="btnSaveData_OnClick" />
```

The event handler of the button click should check if the data already exists. If so, the client script is registered; if not, the new data is saved.

```
protected void btnSaveData_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the data record already exists
    bool isDuplicate = ...

    if (isDuplicate)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ConfirmSave", "confirmSaveData();", true);
    }
    else
    {
        DoSaveData();
    }
}

private void DoSaveData()
{
    // Actually save the data
    ...
}
```

The Javascript function asks for confirmation. If the user confirms, the value of the hidden field is set to `true` and the form is submitted again; if not, the saving operation is canceled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmSaveData() {
        if (confirm("Duplicate data. Do you want to overwrite?")) {
            var hiddenOverwriteData = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenOverwriteData.ClientID %>');
            hiddenOverwriteData.value = 'true';
            form1.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

In `Page_Load`, we check if the user has just confirmed that the duplicate data should be overwritten, in which case the data is saved and the hidden field value is reset.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hiddenOverwriteData.Value == "true")
    {
        hiddenOverwriteData.Value = "false";
        DoSaveData();
    }
}
```